# TypeError when issuing destroyRecord on hasMany items on model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

### Ember Info

**Ember Version:** 2.8.3

**Ember Data Version:** 2.8.1

### Broken Code

I am getting an error when iterating through a hasMany relationship on an Ember-data model.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Here is the code that is getting the error:

```
question.get('question-options').then(options => {
  options.forEach(option => {
    option.destroyRecord();
  });
});
question.set('kind', target.value);
```

A little background on the code. The **question** has a type and we remove the associated **question-options** when changing the type. In reality this is only happening to non-persisted questions (no **id** present).

In the above code if I replace `option.destroyRecord()` with `console.log(option.get('text'))`. Things work fine.

I can also get things to work they way I want them to by adding `toArray()` before the `forEach`. This is what I'm doing as a work-around but I wanted to see if anyone had any ideas why it was behaving this way.

### Working Code with toArray()

```
question.get('question-options').then(options => {
  options.toArray().forEach(option => {
    option.destroyRecord();
  });
});
question.set('kind', target.value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, thats expected behavior. The problem is that the `options`-`hasMany`-array is a live-array. So it's updated whenever you add or remove data from the store. And thats what you're doing with `destroyRecord`. So you are basically modifying the array while looping through it. And this will mess up with `forEach`/is just not supported.

what also would work is something like this I think (but also not reliable):

```
while(options.get('firstObject')){
  options.get('firstObject').destroyRecord();
}
```

I think going with `toArray` **is** the right solution.